# Acts 7:51 What does it mean to be both "uncircumcised in heart and ears"?

Tags: acts, idiom

What does it mean to be both "uncircumcised in heart and ears"?

In Acts 7 Stephen gives a speech where he says in Acts 7:51 NKJV:

> <sup>**51**</sup> “You stiff-necked and uncircumcised in heart and
> ears! You always resist the Holy Spirit; as your fathers did, so do
> you.

From the context it is fairly clear that they are "not listening" to him and resisting the Holy Spirit and therefore not taking his words to heart. Is that how this should be interpreted? If so, why does he use this phrase to say so? It's an unusual metaphor, especially "uncircumcised ears".

Answer (score 1):

The key to understanding this is the rite of circumcision itself, or more correctly, what the rite represented.  We do not need to wonder about this - circumcision of the flesh represented an inner conversion which the OT consistently calls, "circumcision of the heart"; ie, dedicating the inner thought, and by extension, the whole being to God.  Note the following sample -

- Deut 10:16 - Circumcise your hearts, therefore, and stiffen your necks no more. [ie, bow before God = dedicate yourselves to God]
- Deut 30:6 - The LORD your God will circumcise your hearts and the hearts of your descendants, and you will love Him with all your heart and with all your soul, so that you may live. [Compare the Shema in Deut 6:4, 5.]
- Jer 4:4 - Circumcise yourselves to the LORD, and remove the foreskins of your hearts, O men of Judah and people of Jerusalem. Otherwise, My wrath will break out like fire and burn with no one to extinguish it, because of your evil deeds.”
- Rom 2:29 - No, a man is a Jew because he is one inwardly, and circumcision is a matter of the heart, by the Spirit, not by the written code. Such a man’s praise does not come from men, but from God.

Now, recall that Stephen was addressing a room full of physically circumcised men.  When he called them "uncircumcised in heart", he was effectively accusing them of carrying out the symbol but ignoring what the symbol represented.

Note that in the above texts, circumcision of the heart is equivalent (Deut 30:6) to loving the LORD, "with all your heart and with all your soul".  In Matt 22:37 Jesus declared this the greatest commandment (with which the scribes a pharisees agreed, Mark 12:32).  Thus, it might be argued that Stephan was accusing them of being non-spiritual Jews, insincere, etc.

To the Sanhedrin this was the greatest spiritual insult to their spiritual arrogance and pride.  Little wonder that they immediately carried Stephen to his execution.

Answer (score 1):

Circumcision of heart means the same thing that it does in the apparent OT reference:

Deuteronomy 10

> 16 Circumcise therefore the foreskins of your hearts, and be
> stiff-necked no longer.

The idea is that the heart is cloaked rather than vulnerable and open to God. There is also an implication of stubbornness in "stiff-necked."

The circumcision of ears a concept used rarely in the OT, but the meaning is similar. Stephen may be thinking of Jeremiah 6:10:

> To whom shall I speak?
> whom shall I warn, and be heard? See! their ears are uncircumcised,
> they cannot pay attention.

Both metaphors refer to Stephen's claim that God's people were not open to Him. They could not feel what God felt, nor could they hear the new revelation of God's word.